# Calling an overridden base method conditionally in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've never really been poised with this question: But would it be a terrible crime to call base.SomeMethod() conditionally in an overridden method?

Example as in:

```
protected override void SomeMethod()
{ 
     if( condition > 0 ) 
        base.SuperMethod(); 
}
```

I'm aware that this may be considered bad practice but I've actually never read such a claim so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't think of a reason why this would be bad off the top of my head.

It'd be a lot worse to override the base method and copy the base method's functionality to conditionally call instead of just calling the base method.

Answer (score 7):

```
class HardHearingPerson : Person
{
  override void Listen() 
  { 
    if (volume.Acceptable()) 
      base.Listen(); 
  }
}
```

Guess it depends on the context, but I am sure it could have justified usage.

Answer (score 2):

I do this quite often. Every time I need to "do something more" in a method I override it do my stuff and invoke the base method (or vice versa)

Comment: Are you missing the 'conditionally' part?

Comment: @leppie: No. The "do something more" can include conditionals

Answer (score 1):

I think it is totally acceptable.  You might want to override the behaviour of a base class method only under certain circumstances, or extend the behaviour by calling the base method then doing your own thing.

Comment: That might justify another class (specialization)  :)

Comment: @leppie - doesn't inheriting a class count as creating another class? Take this example:  class CSharpProgrammer inherits  class Programmer...  CSharpProgrammer is a specialised class based on Programmer.

Answer (score 1):

**Classes should be [designed for inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):**

> > **If the base class is designed in a manner where calling base versions of certain methods is optional then it's ok to omit those calls.**
> >
> > **If the base class is designed in a manner where base versions MUST be called then it is not ok to omit them.**

Discussing whether this is a "good practice" misses the point, in my opinion. The way in which a class is structured for inheritance is based on its purpose and design. The decision of *whether* you **MAY** or **MUST** call base versions of a method is part of the classes *public interface*, with respect to inheritance.

You can't decide when it will be desirable or not desirable to call a base class method when you override without understanding how the base class is designed and what purpose each method serves.